Update airflow config without restarting scheduler with LocalExecutor
I have a bunch of tasks running and want to update airflow.cfg to enable more tasks to run simultaneously. My understanding is that I need to restart the scheduler for these updates to take place. However, when I try to restart the scheduler, I get this warning:

INFO - Shutting down LocalExecutor; waiting for running tasks to finish.  Signal again if you don't want to wait.

Is there any way for me to update the config without killing ongoing jobs or having to wait (potentially days) for the currently running jobs to finish?

The short answer:

No

And that makes sense. It's an application initialization file that includes database / logging / mail server / etc settings. These settings are loaded into the memory
